# AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'coroutine'>`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-asyncio, asgi

I want to async view with my django rest framework `api_view` but I am getting the above error even if I had awaited my response. Here is my view

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@authentication_classes([])
async def login(request):
    email = request.data.get('email')
    if email is None or email == '':
        return Response(data={'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid credentials'})

    user = await sync_to_async(User.get_by_email)(email=email)

    if user is not None and user.is_active and user.check_password(raw_password=request.data.get('password')):
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        # TODO async
        tokens_map = await sync_to_async(AuthUtils.generate_token)(request=request, user=user)
        return Response({'success': True, 'user': serializer.data, 'tokens': tokens_map})

    return Response(data={'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid login credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Is there any way to use async views with django in an efficient way?

Also for async views will the traditional django middlewares needs to changed?

Comment: For things like this, where there is no mention whatsoever of a feature in the official documentation, the first thing I would do is check the official issue tracker. There you'll find very long threads about the topic, such as [this one](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/8496). It does not look like this is properly supported yet and it seems far from trivial to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to handle `else` part of `user is None`

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@authentication_classes([])
async def login(request):
    email = request.data.get('email')
    if email is None or email == '':
        return Response(data={'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid credentials'})
    else:
        user = await sync_to_async(User.get_by_email)(email=email)

        if user is not None and user.is_active and user.check_password(raw_password=request.data.get('password')):
            serializer = UserSerializer(user)
            # TODO async
            tokens_map = await sync_to_async(AuthUtils.generate_token)(request=request, user=user)
            return Response({'success': True, 'user': serializer.data, 'tokens': tokens_map})
        else:
            return Response(data={'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid login credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```